# python Beautifulsoup4 package installing

Tags: beautifulsoup

I've trying to install beautifulsoup4 package for my mac.
I was following the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM-L1rvTpwU).

I got up to where it's 1:40 in the video to upgrade the version of beautifulsoup.
But my terminal throws the error and this is how it looks:
[image]

could you guys help me how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `pip install bs4`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

as unix based system needs superuser permission to write unless you are installing it in a `virtualenv`